# @ConfigurationProperties vs @PropertySource vs @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring/Spring Boot. I want to use the key-value pair data of `application.properties` / `application.yml` in Java file. I know that we can use `@Value` in any POJO class to set a default value of a field from `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

Q1) But then why do we need the other two? `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@PropertySource`.

Q2) `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@PropertySource`, both can be used to load external data mentioned in `application.properties` or `application.yml` file? Or any restrictions?

PS: I have tried to search on internet but didn't get a clear answer.

Comment: You can check difference here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`@Value("${spring.application.name}")`  @Value will throw exception if there no matching key in application.properties/yml file. It strictly injects property value.

For example: `@Value("${spring.application.namee}")` throws below exception, as `namee` field doesn't exists in properties file.

```
application.properties file
----------------------
spring:
  application:
    name: myapplicationname


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testValue': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.namee' in value "${spring.application.namee}"

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.namea' in value "${spring.application.namee}"
```

`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myserver.allvalues")` injects POJO properties, it's not strict, it ignores the property if there is no key in properties file.

For example:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myserver.allvalues")
public class TestConfigurationProperties {
    private String value;
    private String valuenotexists; // This field doesn't exists in properties file
                                   // it doesn't throw error. It gets default value as null
}

application.properties file
----------------------
myserver:
  allvalues:
    value:  sampleValue
```

Comment: and what about @PropertySource

Answer (score 24):

`@ConfigurationProperties` is used on a POJO bean to map properties to its fields or setters. Then you can use the bean to access the property values in your application logic.

`@PropertySource` is to reference a properties file and load it into the Spring environment (where it may be used by @ConfigurationProperties or @Value).

`@Value` is to inject a particular property value by its key into a variable (member field or constructor argument).

Answer (score -1):

<sub><sup>Base on my research & understanding::</sup></sub>

- `@ConfigurationProperties`

  loads properties from `application.properties`

  you specify the field names to correspond to the names of the properties in `application.properties`

  -- `@ConfigurationProperties` does not work with `@Value`
- `@PropertySource`

  loads properties from a file you specify

  can use with `@Value` or `@Autowired Environment env;`
- `@Value`

  it is used with `application.properties`

  `application.properties` is loaded by default (you dont need to specify in `@PropertySource`)

---

Reference

> - 
>
> https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/
>
> https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/
>
> -
>
> SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:
>
> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
>
> -
>
> @ConfigurationProperties annotation. When placed on any Spring bean, it specifies that the properties of that bean can be injected from properties in the Spring environment.
>
> < Spring In Action >
>
> -
>
> You can bundle the configuration file in your application jar or put the file in the filesystem of the runtime environment and load it on Spring Boot startup.
>
> Spring Boot loads the application.properties file automatically from the project classpath.
>
> http://dolszewski.com/spring/spring-boot-application-properties-file/
>
> -
>
> 4.1. application.properties: the Default Property File
>
> Boot applies its typical convention over configuration approach to property files. This means that we can simply put an application.properties file in our src/main/resources directory, and it will be auto-detected. We can then inject any loaded properties from it as normal.
>
> So, by using this default file, we don’t have to explicitly register a PropertySource or even provide a path to a property file.
>
> https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring
>
> -
>
> @ConfigurationProperties indicates to spring that it should bind the java fields based on their name to some matching properties.
>
> spring requires that the class that has this annotation must be a spring bean
>
> [Spring Inject Values with @ConfigurationProperties and @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801784/spring-inject-values-with-configurationproperties-and-value)

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value` do not only load from `application.properties` but from all 17 sources listed at the top of this page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: This answer makes it sound like the difference between the annotations is in which files it loads. But the main difference is more than that, as other answers on this page indicate.