# Difference between @Value and @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Difference between @Value and @ConfigurationProperties?
In which scenario should I use @Value or @ConfigurationProperties?
@RefreshScope will refresh properties value for both?

Comment: Value comes from spring framework, configuration properties from boot. When /refresh is called 2 things happen, configuration properties are rebound and the RefreshScope cache is cleared. If you need properties to update at runtime use configuration properties first

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for a quick response. Is it not possible to update values at runtime using RefreshScope for Value annotated properties?

Comment: It is, but refresh scope creates a new instance of the bean, not just refresh values of an existing one.

Comment: @spencergibb It would be better for me to understand it clearly if you share the source of the internal working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@ConfigurationProperties vs @PropertySource vs @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691325/configurationproperties-vs-propertysource-vs-value)

Comment: ..and very well answered by chapter 2, 2.8, and esp. [2.8.10](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation)

Answer (score 3):

I was questioning the same, to myself, and I found a concrete reason and why is better to use `ConfigurationProperties` over `Value`.

The main reason is that you could end with some text in the code forcing you to do full-text search to understand where a `Value` property is used.

You can find the whole explanation in in this lightweith reading: https://tuhrig.de/why-using-springs-value-annotation-is-bad/

Answer (score 0):

Insteead of using @Value annotation multiple time to read value from properties file .we can use @configurationProperties one time